# Git commit with auto-tag and subtag

Tags: git

Suppose my team is about to work on **Sprint 15**.

Is there a way I can set all commits from now on to carry a tag such as `sprint15`?

Going even a little further, if all commits are already auto-tagging `sprint15`, can I manually add a second tag such as `pbi120` to the commit?

Comment: I miss an explanation of what exactly you want to achieve and why.

Comment: A tag points at a single commit, so it's unclear how you would expect "all commits from now on to carry a tag". Perhaps you want a branch instead of a tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at git hook example in project_dir/.git/hooks/commit-msg.sample. You can use this to add whatever tag you want to the commits.

For example:

```
branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

if [[ $branch == issues/* ]]; then
  link=$(echo $branch | awk -F/ '{ print "[username/reponame#"$2"]" }')
  echo "issue link: $link"
  echo $link >> $1
fi

exit 0
```